# How can I capture a list of all servers my computer connects to?

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I'd like to capture, in real-time, a list of all servers (URL preferred, IP address ok) my computer connects to. I've used `tshark` and `tcpdump`, but they return different results. This makes me wonder if I'm getting erroneous items or missing some.

Here's a sample from `tcpdump`:

```
08:28:36.250775 IP 155.246.200.17.52012 > a72-247-9-129.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com.http: tcp 0
```

And from `tshark`:

```
2   0.005753 155.246.149.79 -> 155.246.200.17 DNS 103 Standard query response 0xab8b A star-mini.c10r.facebook.com A 31.13.73.36
```

I seem to get more things like photo and ad servers using `tshark`, and definitely see different results when visiting the same sites.

Is there a better solution to capture this? (I'm on a Mac, but Linux solutions might work too.)

Comment: If you could post the results to see how they differ that would be helpful.

Comment: Also are you using Linux (I am assuming you are using Linux) or Windows?

Comment: You say you want URLs. Does that mean you only want a list of _web_ servers, or other kinds as well? (Many protocols don't really use URLs.) Did you actually mean "URL" or just "hostname"/"domain name"?

Comment: Good points all: question updated with output results. I'm on a Mac. Re URLs, I'm not really sure what that means, but I want things like `ec2-52-2-147-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com`.